# Are there any Christian sects that believe in "curative intercourse"?

Tags: sexuality, entertainment

A lot of episodes from the Law and Order franchise seem to draw inspiration from real life events, however, with a recent episode (*[Law & Order: SVU Season 18 Episode 19: Conversion](https://www.tvfanatic.com/2017/05/law-and-order-svu-season-18-episode-19-review-conversion/)*), I'm wondering whether the writers "jumped the shark": they portrayed a weird "Christian" sect that actually believe in something they call "curative intercourse" - in the words of the character Rollins, they believe "you can rape the gay out of someone".

It seems a little far-fetched to me that this would actually be taught by any group that claims to be Christian, but with groups like [Westboro](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Westboro_Baptist_Church), I suppose anything is possible - is there any group that identifies as Christian that actually teaches any doctrine that resembles this?

Comment: If a Christian group does teach it, does that automatically make it a Christian teaching?

Comment: @fredsbend Not likely, more chance for it to be heretical or schismatic.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is such a thing as [corrective rape](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corrective_rape) that is practiced in parts of Africa, India, and Thailand. However, it is generally rooted in cultural ideas of heteronormativity and is most often used as a form of retribution or punishment for perceived lewdness rather than any specific curative religious ideology.  While anything is possible in the world of fringe cults, I have never heard nor could I find any evidence of any Christian sect or cult that practices it as a tenet of their faith.

A quick Google search of the phrase "curative intercourse" just leads to a few pages of links referring to that episode of SVU before veering off-topic. It looks like the writers of SVU coined the phrase themselves.